# Isolate and shared scope same time in directive AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, controller, scope, directive, angular-directive

New to Angular so not sure if I ask my question the right way.

So I have form.

```
<form ng-controller="myController" action="" method="get">
    <div myDirective> 
       <input ng-model="question.sex" value="male" type="radio">
       <input ng-model="question.sex" value="female" type="radio">
       <button ng-click="log(LogThisQuestionAnsware())"></button>
    </div>
    <div myDirective> 
       <input ng-model="question.agree" value="no" type="radio">
       <input ng-model="question.agree" value="yes" type="radio">\
       <button ng-click="log(LogThisQuestionAnsware())"></button>
    </div>
</form>
```

So my goal is to log current "question" answer. on button click.

How can I access local question in myDirective separate from my second directive and have in controller scope too.

--[ Edit: ]--

Ok this is pretty much my scenario. [http://jsfiddle.net/y5esnm09/5](http://jsfiddle.net/y5esnm09)
Each button have to log its own directive value not both radio values if they are selected.

Comment: do both directives have to bind to the same question object but have their own scopes, separate from eachother?

Comment: yes think that is what I whant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understood your question, you want both directive instances to bind to the same question object, but have their scopes separate from eachother:

Set up a two way data binding between your directive and your controller, e.g.:

```
<div my-directive question="question">
 <!-- the rest -->

angular.module('your.module').directive('myDirective', function() {
   return {
      scope: question: '=',
       //other props
   }
```

This will ensure that both directives bind to the same question object but have their own separate scopes.

An alternative would be to set the `scope` property to `true`, that way they will both create a child scope of your controller.

EDIT: Fiddle demonstrating two way binding:

http://jsfiddle.net/L0eqf4qe/

PS: I converted `myDirective` to `my-directive`, angular will translate the snake-case to  camelCase for you.

Comment: angular.module('YourFinancialAdvisor').directive('myDirective', function() {
 return {
  scope: {question: '='},
  link: function(scope, el, attrs) {

   $(el).on('click', function(e) {
    console.log(scope.question); 
   })
  },
 };
});

!! question is undefined !!

Probably I can use attrs.

Comment: @СвободенРоб It shouldn't be undefined, could you post your controller code?

Comment: @СвободенРоб I added a fiddle

Comment: Thanks for the help. Ok this is pretty much my scenario. http://jsfiddle.net/y5esnm09/5 Problem is if both radio are selected on button click a get question object with both values. I need to be separated from each other. Is this possible ?

Comment: @СвободенРоб Off course they log the question object with both values, you're binding them to the same object. If you want different values in each directive you're gonna have to bind them to separate objects

Comment: @СвободенРоб Glad to hear it, if you feel like my answer solved your question, you can mark it as resolved :)